# Protractor Tool for Oracle EBS, Siebel, Peoplesoft, SFDC, pega

Tags: protractor, peoplesoft, oracle-ebs, pega, sfdc

Can anybody help me, Need to know if we can automate tests for "Oracle EBS, Siebel, Peoplesoft, SFDC, pega" applications using Protractor ..?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Protractor might be not the best choice for this. Primary use case of protractor - angular applications

Comment: +1 for actually answering a question here rather than downvoting away.  PS's SO community could do well with being more beginner-friendly.